# How to connect mysql database using esp32 board?

Tags: mysql, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm trying to connect my ESP32 to a server that is running MySQL database on the internal (local) network. But I get the error [E][WiFiClient.cpp:269] connect(): socket error on fd 48, errno: 104, "Connection reset by peer". I've been racking my brains for days and nothing so far...

I'm using the <MySQL_Generic.h> library, I've tried others, but without success. Basically ESP32 connects directly to MySQL, without using PHP files.

I would appreciate if anyone could give me a hint as to what it could be.

Thanks.

```
#include "defines.h"
#include "Credentials.h"
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <MySQL_Generic.h>

#define USING_HOST_NAME     false

#if USING_HOST_NAME
  char server[] = "192.168.0.88/phpmyadmin/";
#else
  IPAddress server(192, 168, 0, 88);
#endif

uint16_t server_port = 3306;    //3306;

MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial && millis() < 5000);

  MYSQL_DISPLAY1("\nStarting Connect_WiFi on", BOARD_NAME);
  MYSQL_DISPLAY(MYSQL_MARIADB_GENERIC_VERSION);

  
#if ( USING_WIFI_ESP8266_AT  || USING_WIFIESPAT_LIB ) 
  #if ( USING_WIFI_ESP8266_AT )
    MYSQL_DISPLAY("Using ESP8266_AT/ESP8266_AT_WebServer Library");
  #elif ( USING_WIFIESPAT_LIB )
    MYSQL_DISPLAY("Using WiFiEspAT Library");
  #endif
  
  
  EspSerial.begin(115200);
  
  WiFi.init(&EspSerial);

  MYSQL_DISPLAY(F("WiFi shield init done"));

  
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD)
  {
    MYSQL_DISPLAY(F("WiFi shield not present"));
    while (true);
  }
#endif

  MYSQL_DISPLAY1("Connecting to", ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);

  setWiFiPowerSavingMode();
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(500);
    MYSQL_DISPLAY0(".");
  }

  MYSQL_DISPLAY1("Connected to network. My IP address is:", WiFi.localIP());
  
  MYSQL_DISPLAY3("Connecting to SQL Server @", server, ", Port =", server_port);
  MYSQL_DISPLAY3("User =", user, ", PW =", password);
}

void setWiFiPowerSavingMode() {
  WiFi.setSleep(false);
}

void loop()
{
  MYSQL_DISPLAY("Connecting...");
  
  if (conn.connect(server, server_port, user, password))
  {
    MYSQL_DISPLAY("Closing connection...");
    conn.close();
  } 
  else 
  {
    MYSQL_DISPLAY("\nConnect failed. Trying again on next iteration.");
  }

  MYSQL_DISPLAY("\nSleeping...");
  MYSQL_DISPLAY("================================================");
 
  delay(60000);
}
```

Comment: Just as an application design note - you would be much better off implementing some sort of PHP / server based API, then using a simple protocol like HTTP with an API key to make your requests from the ESP32. Directly connecting to a database from any end-user device is not a good practice.

Comment: A connection reset means that the server closed the connection before the client was expecting it to. This likely means that the ESP32 library is sending the server that garbage which it is choking on. Are you able to connect to the MySQL server from a command line client / PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: `MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);` Where is `client` defined?

Comment: Hello
@Matt Clark

My server is local, it doesn't have external access (to the world), it's just to record some sensor readings. So there's no problem connecting directly to the ESP32. Regarding the command line connection to MySQL, yes I can...

Comment: @Johnny Mopp. Good, as I took this code from an example, I didn't find where the client is defined. How could I define???

Comment: If this is running on an ESP32 what is going on with EspSerial? Does it ever even connect to WiFi?

Comment: Yes, it connects, below is the serial monitor output:

Comment: .Connected to network. My IP address is: 192.168.0.63
Connecting to SQL Server @ 192.168.0.88 , Port = 3306
User = rafael , PW = aY1)@hw-S8r1/y0L
Connecting...
[  1692][E][WiFiClient.cpp:269] connect(): socket error on fd 48, errno: 104, "Connection reset by peer"

Connect failed. Trying again on next iteration.

Comment: Then the EspSerial/Wifi.init() calls make no sense and this code doesn't remotely compile. 

Connection reset by peer means that you have the wrong port number, the port is blocked by a firewall, the server isn't running or the server isn't listening on that port. You'll have to figure that out for yourself.

Comment: You are assuming that mysql server talk to a mysql client using plain-text TCP. That's not the case, that's why there is always a web server (whether it run php or other language is another story) that take in the tcp/http requests from the web and go through a mysql (Unix-socket) client to talk to the mysql server.

Comment: @romkey - of course it compiles. He is [literally using the example](https://github.com/khoih-prog/MySQL_MariaDB_Generic/blob/master/examples/WiFi/Connect_Disconnect_WiFi/Connect_Disconnect_WiFi.ino) provided by the library. He wouldn't be able to tell you that he was getting a connection reset if it didn't compile / install.

Comment: @romkey - You are very incorrect about the connection reset. A _connection reset_ means that the server responded to an initial request, but then closed the stream unexpectedly at a later time. If a firewall were preventing the flow, you would see a _connection timeout_. If no application were bound to the service port, you would see a _connection refused_.

Comment: @hcheung - applications like PhpMyAdmin use an HTTP layer, yes, however the port 3306 that he is attempting to connect to is the proper transport port for MySQL communications, and is not HTTP based.

Comment: @RafaelFreeseGuerreiro - is your MySQL user setup for remote access, or only local? `use mysql; select User,Host from user` - you should have at least one line item that allows you to login from a remote host, i.e., `root @ %`

Comment: @MattClark No. Connection reset is when TCP issues a reset packet. This happens when nothing is active on the port, or when the process which was providing service on that port exits. It's also a common response for firewalls, which can generally be configured in several different ways. There is no difference between "connection refused" and "connection reset".